# Create child processes inside a child process with Python multiprocessing failed

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I observed this behavior when trying to create nested child processes in Python. Here is the parent program `parent_process.py`:

```
import multiprocessing
import child_process

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
for i in range(4):
        pool.apply_async(child_process.run, ())
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The parent program calls the "run" function in the following child program child_process.py:

```
import multiprocessing

def run():
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
        print 'TEST!'
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

When I run the parent program, nothing was printed out and the program exited quickly. However, if `print 'TEST!'` is moved one line above (before the nested child processes are created), `'TEST!'` are printed for 4 times.

Because errors in a child process won't print to screen, this seems to show that the program crashes when a child process creates its own nested child processes.

Could anyone explain what happens behind the scene? Thanks!

Comment: I know there is a limit in nesting that raises an Exception, but you are far from it in this case. I think the issue in somewhere else, maybe in the `pool` mechanism...

Comment: What are you trying to improve with this? You won't be faster by launching pools of `Pool` than launching a bigger `Pool`

Comment: @HarryPotfleur The intention was to let each child process manage its own set of processes, so the program looks cleaner logically. Say I have 16 cores, then the 4x4 nested processes can simultaneously run. I provide a workaround below.

Comment: in this case you could spawn 4 `multiprocessing.Process`, each of them launching a `Pool`. I can help you with the code if you need

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon), daemonic processes cannot spawn child processes.

`multiprocessing.Pool` uses daemonic processes to ensure that they don't leak when your program exits.

Answer (score 6):

As noxdafox said, `multiprocessing.Pool` uses daemonic processes. I found a simple workaround that uses `multiprocess.Process` instead:

Parent program:

```
import multiprocessing
import child_process

processes = [None] * 4
for i in range(4):
    processes[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target=child_process.run, args=(i,))
    processes[i].start()
for i in range(4):
    processes[i].join()
```

Child program (with name `child_process.py`):

```
import multiprocessing

def test(info):
    print 'TEST', info[0], info[1]

def run(proc_id):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(test, [(proc_id, i) for i in range(4)])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The output is 16 lines of `TEST`:

```
TEST 0 0
TEST 0 1
TEST 0 3
TEST 0 2
TEST 2 0
TEST 2 1
TEST 2 2
TEST 2 3
TEST 3 0
TEST 3 1
TEST 3 3
TEST 3 2
TEST 1 0
TEST 1 1
TEST 1 2
TEST 1 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to post a comment, but since python version determines the options for running hierarchical multiprocessing (e.g., [a post from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491558/launching-nested-processes-in-multiprocessing)), I wanted to share my experience. The above solution by Da Kuang worked for me with python 3.7.1 running through Anaconda 3.

I made a small modification to child_process.py to make it run the cpu for a little while so I could check system monitor to verify 16 simultaneous processes were running.

```
import multiprocessing

def test(info):
    print('TEST', info[0], info[1])
    aa=[1]*100000
    a=[1 for i in aa if all([ii<1 for ii in aa])]
    print('exiting')

def run(proc_id):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(test, [(proc_id, i) for i in range(4)])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```