# Pool to Celery group

Tags: python, multiprocessing, celery

I'm using Celery to launch a task, this task includes a port scanner which is built using multiprocessing and ThreadPool. When I launch it I get the following error, looking for an alternative or tutorial to migrate my existing code:

```
[2015-10-25 18:53:57,090: ERROR/Worker-3] daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/test/utils/port_scanner.py", line 57, in is_port_opened
    ports = list(scan_ports(server=server, port=int(port)))
  File "/Users/user/Documents/OpenSource/Development/Python/test/utils/port_scanner.py", line 37, in scan_ports
    p = Pool(NUM_CORES)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 159, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 223, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 124, in start
    'daemonic processes are not allowed to have children'
AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

This is my code:

```
import socket
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from errno import ECONNREFUSED

NUM_CORES = 4
def portscan(target, port):
    try:
        # Create Socket
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(12)
        s.connect((target, port))
        print 'port_scanner.is_port_opened() ' + str(port) + " is opened"
        return port
    except socket.error as err:
        print str(err)
        if err.errno == ECONNREFUSED:
            return False


# Wrapper function that calls portscanner
def scan_ports(server=None, port=None, portStart=None, portEnd=None, **kwargs):
    p = Pool(NUM_CORES)
    ping_host = partial(portscan, server)

    if portStart and portStart:
        # Filter returns Booleans
        return filter(bool, p.map(ping_host, range(portStart, portStart)))
    else:
        return filter(bool, p.map(ping_host, range(port, port + 1)))


# Check if port is opened
def is_port_opened(server=None, port=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        # check if its IP Address:
        ports = list(scan_ports(server=server, port=int(port)))
        if len(ports) != 0:
            print 'port_scanner.is_port_opened() ' + str(len(ports)) + " port(s) available."
            return True
        else:
            print 'port_scanner.is_port_opened() port not opened: (' + str(port) + ')'
            return False

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_port_opened(server='110.10.0.144', port=22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is pretty close to the one experienced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688946/create-child-processes-inside-a-child-process-with-python-multiprocessing-failed/32689245#32689245).
Daemonic processes cannot spawn child processes. The reason behind it, is because a daemonic process gets terminated forcefully by its parent. But if the parent would be a daemonic process as well, it would be terminated forcefully without having time to do the same with its child.

`multiprocessing.Pool` uses daemonic processes to ensure they don't leak when your program extits. I assume Celery does the same to run your task. Therefore you're spawning daemonic processes within a daemon process.

A possible solution would be to quickly implement a Pool of processes yourself using `Process` and `Queue` objects from [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) library. You would spawn non daemonic processes and feed them through a queue.