# Python distributed ThreadPool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, threadpool, pathos

Do any of the Python ThreadPool packages (multiprocessing, pathos) distribute worker threads across multiple cpus?  If not would I need to need to create a ProcessPool, then create a ThreadPool on each ProcessPool worker?

Comment: `multiprocessing` does that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author.  `multiprocessing` has a `Pool` that will distribute jobs to multiple cpus.  Here's an example (using `multiprocess`, which is a fork of `multiprocessing` with better serialization):

```
>>> import multiprocess as mp
>>> mp.Pool().map(lambda x:x, range(4))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

`pathos` uses `multiprocess` in `pathos.pools.ProcessPool`.  There's also `pathos.pools.ParallelPool` (from `ppft`) that can spawn jobs with distributed computing (not on the same machine).

If you are looking to do a hierarchical pool (i.e. `ThreadPool` and `ProcessPool`), then you should use `pathos` for that.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28491924/2379433 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613077/2379433 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/40852258/2379433.

However, you could do it with `multiprocessing`... but I think it's no longer allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963618/2379433